# Nautilus remote server doesn't remember specific folder

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, nautilus

I'm accessing a remote folder on my server by doing this:

1. Opening Nautilus
2. Going to **Connect to Server**
3. Writing **sftp://user@server/specific-folder**

This works just fine the first time I connect, Nautilus displays the specific folder rather than displaying the user's home folder. However if I close Nautilus, the shortcut saved on the left panel inside of Nautilus will just show the default user's folder rather than the one I specified.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this as far as I'm seeing, I found a workaround so I'm just going to share that. If anyone has an actual solution I'd still like to hear it.

1. Opening Nautilus
2. Going to Connect to Server
3. Writing sftp://user@server/specific-folder
4. Add folder to bookmarks

The folder should now appear to the shortcuts on the left panel of nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a server to the bookmarks, the home folder of the user is the default saved path. You can change it on:

- Nautilus > Bookmarks (Ctrl+B)

There you can change the path the bookmark is going to access.